# debug python library in visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set a breakpoint in library and debug step by step in visual studio code?
For example,

TestApi.py

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
iqoptionapi=IQ_Option("test","test")
```

If I put a breakpoint at `iqoptionapi=IQ_Option("test","test")` I want it to go to `IQ_Option` and debug it there as well.

Is this possible in Python? I'm using Python 3.7

I followed this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types).

1. python options was not loaded in add configuration
2. So I manually added this section

```
{
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },

    {
      "name": "Debug Unit Test",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "test",
      "justMyCode": false,
    }
```

Then I pressed F5 to debug but it skipped.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: @rioV8  yes please see the update

Comment: i fixed it moving `justmycode` to above section worked

Comment: I tested it with a test program using `html.parser.HTMLParser`. Using `justMyCode=true` does not go into the library source code, `justMyCode=false` steps into the library with `F11`.